# Mapping from symmetric power to a lower symmetric power

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This may be a dumb question, but what are the surjective maps
$$f_n:\operatorname{Sym}^n(V)\to \operatorname{Sym}^{n-2}(V),$$
where Sym$^n$ denotes the $n$-th symmetric power of $V$? Wouldn't it just be a projection? And what is the kernel of such a map (if it's not trivial)?

Comment: If you want the maps to be compatible with some structure,  you should tell us which. For example, ghere are no such maps which are $GL(V)$-equivariant. If you care simply for linearity, then there are many surjective maps, and the only important thing is the dimension of the vector spaces involved.

Comment: So say that the $V$'s above are linear representations, or wedge products/symmetric powers of such representations. All I want is the map to be surjective, and the kernel of the map to be an irreducible representation. Shouldn't something like a projection map work?

Comment: What do you mean by "a projection map"? A linear representation of what?

Comment: Linear representation of *what*? The answer very much depends on this.

Comment: I was thinking of a linear representation of, say, a Lie algebra. I think I meant projection as, say, eliminating terms of degree $n$ and $n-1$ in the polynomial as in the example below, but maybe I am not making sense...

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminating terms of degree $n$ and $n-1$"?

Comment: Ah, forget I said that. I understand your example now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is a real vector space equipped with an inner product. Then, thinking of $\text{Sym}^n(V)$ as homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in $\dim V$ variables, an example of such a map which is $\text{O}(V)$-invariant is given by the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator). Explicitly, if $x_1, ... x_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then take

$$\Delta = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}.$$

The kernel of the Laplacian is the space of harmonic polynomials of degree $n$, and I believe this is an irreducible representation of $\text{O}(V)$.

As Mariano says, if you want $\text{GL}(V)$-invariance, there are no such maps if $\dim V \ge 2$: in fact $\text{Sym}^n(V)$ are all irreducible representations of $\text{GL}(V)$ (in characteristic zero!) of different dimensions.

Comment: This is the correct example.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $n$-th symmetric power can be identified with homogenous polynomials in $\dim V$ variables of degree $n$. The obvious surjection is just evaluation of some variables at 1.

Comment: This doesn't reduce the degree, it reduces the number of variables.